# Volume of two intersecting tetrahedra in CGAL

Tags: boolean, volume, intersection, cgal, tetrahedra

I am looking for a fast way to compute the **volume of the intersection of two tetrahedra** using CGAL.
If I read and understood the CGAL manual correctly I could create the two tetrahedra as 3D Nef Polyhedra, then compute their intersection as 3D Nef Polyhedron and calculate its volume.

Is that correct or are there better/easier way to accomplish this?

The final goal of this is to create an algorithm which creates a mapping between two tetrahedral meshes. (how much of element-i in mesh a is included in element-j in mesh b).